# How find the next table tbody jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the table next to the Clicked Button.
All tables and Buttons are Dynamically created.

```
<button type="button" onclick="addRows(this)">Add Row</button>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="addRows(this)">Add Row</button>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>B</td>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="addRows(this)">Add Row</button>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>C</td>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="addRows(this)">Add Row</button>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using this but I can get the next table to the Button:

```
$(this).closest("table").find("tbody");
```

Comment: Avoid inline event handlers like `onclick="addRows(this)"`

Comment: Yes you can use next for this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.next()` to get the next element.

```
$(this).next("table").find("tbody")
```

`.closest()` is for finding the closest **containing** element, not an adjacent element. Since the button isn't inside a table, `$(this).closest("table")` doesn't match anything.

Boy did the jQuery designers screw up when they named this. It seems to be the most common source of confusion among newbies.